# check if foreign key is used in other tables before delete data row hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have the following table structure:

```
table A 
---------
id | name

table B
--------------
id | x | y | z

table B (id) : references table A (id)
```

I can modify name of `table A` even if data present at `table B` for id of table A ,
as it is not a foreign key.

Now I want to restrict the modification of name variable of `table A`, if `id` of `table A` has records in other table.
Do I need to query each table where `id` of `table A` is used as foreign key, or there is any other option in Hibernate or MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that right in the database via a constraint on the key the foreign key refers to. The database will then take the action you specify automatically.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more

Comment: @HKumar SQL has CONSTRAINT options when you define a foreign key that determine what happens when that key is updated or deleted in the foreign table it is defined in. You can set it to cascade the update/delete into the current table, or to restrict the operation so it causes a constraint-violation error instead of succeeding, or to set the foreign key value to null in the current table, or to do nothing, in which case the foreign key is no longer valid. You need to investigate all this thoroughly.